# Hide Form From alt-tab without lose control box

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winapi

I'm using **Windows API** To Hide 3rd Party Application *form*
from alt-tab using this piece of code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr window, int index, int value);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr window, int index);

int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
int WS_EX_APPWINDOW;

private void Hide_AltTab(IntPtr x)
{
     //Get and store Current Style before Hide
     WS_EX_APPWINDOW = GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
     //Hide
     SetWindowLong(x, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
}

private void Show_AltTab(IntPtr x)
{
     //Restore Default Style
     SetWindowLong(x, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
}
```

this code work good To hide *form* from alt-tab
**But** My Problem is :
when i hide *form* from alt-tab the Control Box is disappeared

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

**So** what is the value in WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW i have to use to hide *form* from alt-tab and keep the ControlBox?

Comment: Your Hide_AltTab() method is nonsense, it doesn't change the style flag at all.  You must post the code you *actually* use.

Comment: That's a tool window. You need your window to be owned by an invisible window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what is the flag i have to modify ?

Comment: It's not that simple. Normal window. Not a tool window, nor an app window. But you have to make the window be owned by an invisible window.